# Twilio API paging CallResult object in C#

Tags: c#, twilio

When I call ListCalls the CallResult object says I have 49 pages of data, 50 per page.  Is there a way to iterate through the pages in C# using either the Page or NextPageUri?  I noticed setting the Uri property to the NextPageUri does not refresh the data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of properties which you can use to realize grabbing loop:

1. CallListRequest.Count  - records count you'd like to get.
2. CallListRequest.PageNumber - the page with data you'd like to get
3. CallResult.NumPages - the total number of pages from your call result.

At the end you can use something like this to get all pages data from twilio API:

```
 var client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);
             var request = new CallListRequest();
             request.Count = 1000;//1000 - is max value
             request.PageNumber = 0;
             var call = client.ListCalls(request);
             List<TwillioCallRecord> callsToReturn = new List<TwillioCallRecord>();
             if(call.Calls!=null){

             callsToReturn.AddRange(call.Calls.Select(o=>new TwillioCallRecord(){CALL_TO = o.To, DATE_CREATED=o.DateCreated, DATE_UPDATED=o.DateUpdated, DIRECTION=o.Direction, DURATION = o.Duration, END_TIME=o.EndTime, FROM_NAME= person.FullName, PRICE=o.Price, STATUS=o.Status, START_TIME=o.StartTime}));
                 request.PageNumber++;
                  while(call.NumPages>request.PageNumber)
                  {
                      call = client.ListCalls(request);
                      callsToReturn.AddRange(call.Calls.Select(o=>new TwillioCallRecord(){CALL_TO = o.To, DATE_CREATED=o.DateCreated, DATE_UPDATED=o.DateUpdated, DIRECTION=o.Direction, DURATION = o.Duration, END_TIME=o.EndTime, FROM_NAME= person.FullName, PRICE=o.Price, STATUS=o.Status, START_TIME=o.StartTime}));
                      request.PageNumber++;
                  }
             }
```